# rxjs switchMap onerror behavior

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, observable, angular2-http, onerror

I have a confusion about switchMap in rxjs Observable:

for example i have next code:

`Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click')
    .switchMap(() => Observable.fromPromise(fetch('http://return-error.com')))
    .subscribe(
    (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);`

If I get error from fetch, subscription is interrupted. So is there way to handle it to not create new subscription for any error?

I have even tried to catch error and return Observable, but subscription is interrupted anyway.

*upd: how to deal with angular 2 http.get instead of fetch?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always more helpful if you make a Bin when asking these questions.  I did it for you on this one.

You simply need to swallow the error in the fetch call.  E.g.

`fetch('bad-url').catch(err => 'Error but keep going')`

Here's the demo.  Click the document (output) to fire the event.

http://jsbin.com/vavugakere/edit?js,console,output

(You'll need a browser with native Fetch implementation or it'll throw an error)

Comment: thank you, it really works. Do you know how to deal in case of angular 2 http.get instead of fetch?

Comment: @MikhailLinkov I'm glad it helped!  I am a React guy who also loves RxJS.  I don't know Angular's methods.  But if `http.get` returns a promise, you can handle it with a catch.  If it returns an error observable, there are different ways to handle that depending on your needs.

Comment: Angular 2 http returns observable, first way is call toPromise, but you say that trere are different ways, second one is resubscribtion) also I am curious to know is it bug or feature this behavior of switchMap on error, because there is no call onComplete callback after onError

Comment: Seems like I got it, we need to stop propagating error inside switchMap by transforming it into Observable. But this behaviour of switchMap is still not intuitive, also I have not found description of it somewhere. Thank you @D. Walsh once again